# philps hue reachable attribute, how can I fix it

Tags: javascript, philips-hue

I made some window app that can control Bulbs. it works okay for about three months

but one of blubs makes problem. So I was trying to find out what is wrong.

here's xmlhttpRequest (I used CLIP API Debugger)

```
usual blubs: (XMLHttpRequest) id:14

{"state": {

"on": true,

"bri": 254,

"hue": 34704,

"sat": 198,

"effect": "none",

"xy": [

0.3228,

0.3291

],

"ct": 167,

"alert": "none",

"colormode": "xy",

"mode": "homeautomation",

"reachable": true 

}



issue: id:11

{

"state": {

"on": true,

"bri": 254,

"hue": 0,

"sat": 254,

"effect": "none",

"xy": [

0.3227,

0.329

],

"ct": 153,

"alert": "none",

"colormode": "xy",

"mode": "homeautomation",

"reachable": false

},
```

If anyone know this issue please let me know what's wrong with blubs...

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can't control the specific light named id:11. I think it's because of the reachable  attribute. It supposed to be set  "true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reachable` attribute is a read-only attribute (you can't set it), it simply tells you if the light is available or out of reach.
the common causes of a light to be `un-reachable` is that it's set to off, it's out of range or it's dead.
So

- Either turn the switch on
- If it's out of range, add another light between the bridg and that light ( as they work as a pass-through extension too )
- If it's dead replace it
- **Bonus:** If nothing worked try to delete it and re-add it